# Navigation panel level configuration

Tags: navigation, site, configuration, settings

I have a SharePoint 2013 site collection with site that contain 3 level of subsite

Subsite1 > Subsite2 > subsite3

One under the other. When I configure navigation panel in current navigation panel I define structural navigation: display only the navigation items below the current site.

It displays just subsite2 in editing and sorting but when I click ok on the current navigation I have Subsite2 and under  subsite3

I need to have just the subsite2 is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At Current Navigation Setting Make sure that you unchecked `show subsite` at Site 2 Navigation settings

[image]